# How To Only Allow Alpha Numeric Chars With JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Been playing around with JavaScript, and what Im trying to do is only allow certain characters in the pass word field - a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

```
<form action="http://www.cknuckles.com/cgi/echo.cgi" method="get" name="logOn">
  User Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="userName" size="25" /><br />
  Password:<br />
  <input type="password" name="pw" size="25" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Log In" onClick="validate()"/> 
</form>
```

Above is my HTML, and Below is my JavaScript I tried to use to validate it - but it doesnt work - any clues.

```
<script language="javascript">
   document.logOn.onsubmit=validate;

   function validate(){

var name=document.logOn.pw.value;
    if(!name = "[a-zA-Z0-9]"){              
alert("Your Password Cant Have Any Funky Things In It - Play It Straight!");
    return false;
}               

    return true;
}
</script>
```

But This isnt working. I can still put chars in like "*" and "[" and "{" etc.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to make your condition test a regexp, not a string:

```
if(!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(name)){ ...
```

meaning:

- `^` -- start of line
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` -- one or more characters/numbers
- `$` -- end of line

or you could search for the inverse of that, which is "any non-accepted character":

```
if(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(name)){
```

Comment: can you post a running fiddle example...i replaced the if block with the above code and its not working..

Comment: This question is 18 months old.  If you're having problems, post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (name.match(/[\W_]/)) { //...
```

Meaning if the "name" string has any character which is a non-alphanumeric or an underscore then execute the block.  Note that we have to separately check for underscore (`_`) because the alphanumeric character class (`\w`) includes the underscore (so the negative class (`\W`) does *not*).

Answer (score 0):

> The below solution will accept only the alpha numeric value and some
> special key like **backspace**, **delete** etc.
>
> If you want to add some other key then add to the array  .
>
> If you want to add some special symbol add to the same array or create a new array and compare it on the function like ex: `yourNewVariableName.indexOf(e.keyCode)`

```js
var specialKeys = [8, 9, 46, 36, 35, 37, 39];
        function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
            return ret;
        }
```

```html
Alphanumeric value:
<input type="text" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
```