# How to restrict a textbox to accept 10 alphabetic characters only using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to restrict a textbox to accept 10 characters only.If we enter 11th character, it should give a message saying 'you are allowed to enter 10 characters only'.

Comment: Use max length for text box

Comment: @ Let's Code ...I want it not to accept numeric data.I want it to accept alphabets only.

Comment: you will want both front and backend validation of any information you're gathering. if someone forces longer length code to be submitted in your form you you can check it's length using `strlen($inputvalue)` (http://au2.php.net/strlen) and then either trim it to length using `substr($inputvalue, 0, 10)` (http://au1.php.net/substr) or return an error message without accepting the submitted form

Comment: Doing it 'using php' as you asked is not possible or in other words senseless, as that is not php's purpose.

Comment: @codezombie depends if by 'restrict a textbox' he means front end or code that eventually makes it into storage

Comment: @haxxxton - you're right, but the 'give a message' part made me thinking of a frontend check ;)

Comment: @codezombie agreed :)

Comment: @codezombie..I want to perform a front end check.I want the textbox to accept 10 alphabets only.

Comment: @pk2218 have a look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6256040/648350 but remove the 0-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this function:

```
 function check_content(){
        var text = document.getElementById("your_textbox_id").value;
        if(text.length > 10){
            alert('Length should not be greater than 10');
            return false;
        } else { 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:

<input type="text" id="Textbox" name="Textbox" maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for textbox.

```
<input name="mytext" type="text" value='' id="mytext" onkeyup="TextLimit()">
```

and add a javascript function on `keyup` event of textbox.

```
<script>
function TextLimit(){
    var text = document.getElementById('mytext');
   if (text.value.length >= 10){
        alert('you are allowed to enter 10 characters only');

    }
}  
</script>
```