# Numeric Keypad only should Work in Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a Input type as password ,when i try using mobile browser i need to enter input value as numeric only.I want to restrict user even though they enter alphabets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Only Allow Alpha Numeric Chars With JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256008/how-to-only-allow-alpha-numeric-chars-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't done any prior research.

See:
[How To Only Allow Alpha Numeric Chars With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256008/how-to-only-allow-alpha-numeric-chars-with-javascript)

or

[how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

when you used password as input type it will show as *  if you want to show characters/numbers to user as text you can set as text type and later you can change to password. add condition based on user agent to so mobile specific only

```
    $("#password").focus(function(){
      this.type = "text";
      }).blur(function(){
      this.type = "password";
  })
```