# how to display only numbers on a form field and stop other inputs using core javascript?

Tags: javascript

When filling form field only numbers should be taken as input and displayed on the form field.When other characters like 'a' are filled,they are not displayed on the form field .Only previously given numbers are seen.It should be done using core javascript.

Comment: how about `<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="20">` ?

Comment: we have condition that input type should be text:core javascript

Comment: show your efforts, that is 'event handler'

Comment: Thank you...problem solved.I did it using onkeypress event,charCode,keyCode....

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

```
<input type="number">
```

That should be what you need.

**Edit**: After seeing your comment: This is not your solution, because you want a javascript solution. This should have been in your question, because it is essential to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[How To Only Allow Alpha Numeric Chars With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256008/how-to-only-allow-alpha-numeric-chars-with-javascript)

and try to replace the regexp with `if(!/^[0-9]+$/.test(name))`.

Comment: You're welcome...but what about a +1 or sign it as the answer? :)

Comment: Another thing, remember to check the values also server side because a javascript check could be easily by-passed by a malevolent user.